# Filter one Power BI Query based on an Excel Table

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a table called "_Vendor_List" in a spreadsheet and I use this to filter a query in that spreadsheet which I use for analytics.

Similarly, I would like to filter the same query in Power BI based on this same table. This works in excel, but I'm not sure if/how the syntax varies in Power BI for the Query.

My Excel Power Query Code is:

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("MyDatabase", "MY_DATA"),
    ExcelTable = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="_Vendor_List"]}[Content],
    #"PerformanceTable" = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="PerformanceTable"]}[Data],
    Filter = Table.SelectRows(#"PerformanceTable", each List.Contains(ExcelTable[VENDOR], [VENDOR_CODE]))
in
    Filter
```

Now I'm not sure if `CurrentWorkbook` is usable in a power bi, so my question is how do I modify this to now filter the same query in Power BI using the same table (which will also be imported).

Comment: I guess the approach would be to first import `_Vendor_List` into Power BI, then either create a relationship or use DAX to filter measures based on this table

Comment: You can copy the excel power query into the power bi M query editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out as to what the syntax needs to be in order for this filter to work. I couldn't use `CurrentWorkbook` because the Power BI report isn't a workbook; however, you can refer to the `Excel.Workbook` as long as you reference the location.

The one area of improvement I'd like to do is refer to the workbook, not from it's location or drive (as that might change), but instead refer to it within the Power BI Report.

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("MyDatabase", "MY_DATA"),
    #"PerformanceTable" = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="PerformanceTable"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"PerformanceTable",{{"VENDOR_CODE", Int64.Type}}),
    Excel1 = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\myaccount\OneDrive\Power BI\Vendor List.xlsx"), null, true),
    _Vendor_List_Table = Excel1{[Item="_Vendor_List",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    ExcelChange = Table.TransformColumnTypes(_Vendor_List_Table,{{"Vendor", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Group", type text}}),
    Filter = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each List.Contains(ExcelChange[Vendor], [VENDOR_CODE]))
In
    Filter
```